# If we sent out a mailing with an incorrect URL what can we do to fix things up

Tags: civimail

A CiviMailing has just gone out. A link in it was wrong. Is there anything that can be done to rectify the issue so people clicking the link get sent to the right place.

I do have Trackable URL 'on'.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Trackable URL on, and access to DB (or happy using API Explorer) you can probably get yourself out of trouble.

In the db, look for the offending url in the civicrm_mailing_trackable_url table.

Once you find it, update it with the correct url.

Anyone who now clicks on the trackable url link in the mailer should get sent to the updated link